# Azure Pipelines Agent is stuck in Downloading

Tags: azure-devops

For security reasons, I turned on the Windows firewall and blocked incoming and outgoing network traffic.
I created a firewall rule, according to (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops#faq).

Rule allows:

-RemoteAddress 13.107.6.0/24, 13.107.9.0/24, 13.107.42.0/24, 13.107.43.0/24, 2620:1ec:4::/48, 2620:1ec:a92::/48, 2620: 1ec:21::/48, 2620:1ec:22::/48 `

-RemotePort 443

Then the agent was able to connect.

But the agent got stuck in the Downloading mode when I launched "Update agent" via the UI in Azure DevOps.

It is self-hosted agent on Windows Server 2022.

Can you please advise me what else I should allow on the firewall?

[image]